# How do you collect special objects in a class?

Tags: class, object, kotlin

I'm trying to collect several objects of one type (that will have object specific functions as well) in one class/object, so that I can access a list of all of them for some registration.

That would look like this:

```kotlin
open class Item(...) {...}

open class ItemCollection {
    var types = emptySet<Item>() // Can be mutable as well
        private set

    open inner class CollectedItem(...) : Item(...) {
        init { types += this } // Ignore warning for now
    }
}

object ExampleCollection : ItemCollection() {
    object Item1: CollectedItem(...) {
        fun specialForItem1() {...}
    }

    object Item2: CollectedItem(...) {...}
    ...
}
```

This way I can access `ExampleCollection.Item1.specialForItem1()`, but don't have to register each of those collected items to be able to get all of them using `ExampleCollection.types`.

In theory this is fine and disregarding the leakage of `this` this would be a valid solution i my opinion.

But due to [KT-14628](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14628) this currently can't be compiled.
Is there a different or even more elegant way of doing this?

**EDIT:**
One idea would be to use reflection and something like

```kotlin
open class ItemCollection {
    val types: List<Item> by lazy { this::class.nestedClasses.asSequence().map { it.objectInstance }.filterIsInstance<Item>().toList() }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Eliminate the nested class and make the `items` setter protected. Subclasses can register their Item `object`s manually.

Comment: @Tenfour04, what I'm looking for is to get rid of the manual registration inside the ```ExampleCollection```. Using a factory method would not allow me to add special object functions like ```specialForItem1()```, which I actually need.

Comment: Are the Item subclasses all `object`s?

Comment: Don't need to, but in my case I only need one instance of them, so yeah. I think the reflection solution is actually not that bad...

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was trying to describe:

```
open class ItemCollection {
    var types = emptySet<Item>()
        protected set
}

object ExampleCollection : ItemCollection() {
    object Item1: Item() {
        fun specialForItem1() { }
    }

    object Item2: Item()

    init {
        types = setOf(Item1, Item2)
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually is a solution, but I still have to manually keep the ```setOf(Item1, Item2)``` updated, which is prone to be forgotten in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably go with your reflection solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what results in the reflection idea:

```
open class Item(...) {...}

open class ItemCollection {
    val types: List<Item> by lazy { this::class.nestedClasses.asSequence().map { it.objectInstance }.filterIsInstance<Item>().toList() }

    open class CollectedItem(...) : Item(...) // This is now optional but makes my use case more convenient
}

object ExampleCollection : ItemCollection() {
    object Item1: CollectedItem(...) {
        fun specialForItem1() {...}
    }

    object Item2: CollectedItem(...) {...}
    ...
}
```